# Explain Parsing Table at http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I am using the following grammar at http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator :

```
E ->  T E'
E' ->  + T E' 
E' -> EPSILON
T ->  F T'
T' -> * F T'
T' -> EPSILON 
F -> ( E ) 
F ->  id
```

The output Parsing Table is

```
[
        [0, "+", "*", "(", ")", "id", "$"],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 10, 10, 1, 9, 1, 9],
        [0, 2, 10, 10, 3, 10, 3],
        [0, 9, 10, 4, 9, 4, 9],
        [0, 6, 5, 10, 6, 10, 6],
        [0, 9, 9, 7, 9, 8, 9]
]
```

Can somebody explain the parsing table? In particular, what is the meaning of `9` and `10` given that there are only 8 lines in the production rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in the page itself, just above the table:

> If a terminal is absent from a non-terminal's predict set, an error code is placed in the table. If that terminal is in follow(that non-terminal), the error is a POP error. Else, it's a SCAN error.
>
> POP error code = # of predict table productions + 1
>
> SCAN error code = # of predict table productions + 2

So in the case of a grammar with eight production rules, the values 9 and 10 are `POP error` and `SCAN error`, respectively.